# iPhone UIButton addTarget not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

In my iPhone app, I have `SPGameDesk : UIView` class, creating it from other class like:

```
SPGameDesk* gameDesk = [[SPGameDesk alloc] init];
[gameDesk createWithLevel:5];
[appWindow addSubview:gameDesk];
```

In my `SPGameDesk` class, in one method, I create `UIButtons`:

```
holesRow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    [holesRow addObject:[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((40*i)+5, 150, 30, 30)]];
    [[holesRow objectAtIndex:i] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [[holesRow objectAtIndex:i] addTarget:self action:@selector(holeSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview: [holesRow objectAtIndex:i]]; 
}
```

And lower in SPGameDesk class I have method:

```
- (void)holeSelected:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"SELECTED");
}
```

But when I touch my button, nothing happens, like some other `UIView` covers my button (there is no other `UIView`), or like `SPGameDesk` has `userInteraction` disabled (I checked - it is not).

Where is my problem? What should I check?

Comment: You can debug it by cycling through after and seeing what the target and action pointers are (make sure they are not nil and correct.

Comment: Are you sure holesRow isn't being released somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the frame for your gameDesk view?  It looks like it could be 0,0,0,0.  Try setting it to the bounds of the parent window.  Use initwithframe instead of init.

Comment: Yes you are right! I just didn't think about it. Thx for your help!